# Why can't I use a class object as a parameter

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor

I have this problem with getting class to pass as a parameter for another class constructor. Basically the code is like this:

```
class A
{
    public:
       int ID;
       A(int getID)
       {
           ID = getID;
       }
}
```

and I want to use that class A as a member of class B like this:

```
class B
{
    public:
        A someA;
        A someB;
        int number;

    B(A ObjectA, A ObjectB, int getNumber)
    {
        someA = ObjectA;
        someB = ObjectB;
        number = getNumber;
    }
};
```

The errors are basically saying that there is no matching function to call `B::B()`. I don't know whats wrong with it. I have done similar things with vectors of object, so I thought why cant this thing works. Any inputs/correction is appreciated, thank you!

Sidenotes: I have tried adding a default constructor for `B` as suggested in another thread, but it ended up saying invalid use of `B::B`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: Please show how you are instantiating an object of type `B`.

Comment: Too many possible explanations for your problem, and you haven't given enough information.   Providing a [mcve] will help people help you.   If the compiler does not have visibility of class `A` when compiling class `B` - that would be one explanation.   The compiler would issue a large number of error messages in response to that situation BEFORE emitting the error message you describe.

Comment: Ah, sorry the trouble. I copy-paste the exact same code to my linux machine (was using windows) and somehow it works just fine. no error whatsoever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the initialization list for your objects:

```
B(A ObjectA, A ObjectB, int getNumber)
:someA(std::move(ObjectA)), someB(std::move(ObjectB)), number(getNumber)
{
}
```

This will use the default move constructor from your class.

I used `move` here because you are passing your objects by value, so it makes sense to move them. If you passed them by const&, then don't move them and use the default copy constructor.

Still, this is about `A` default constructor, there is no problem with the `B` default constructor in the code you showed.

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because you didn't tell `B` how to initialize its `A` attributes, so it's looking for the default `A` constructor.

In C++ the attribute initialization is made as show by Matthieu, and not in the constructor's body. You can add a default `A` constructor, but you have to think if it's the behavior you want for your code.

Compiling the code below doesn't show any error.

```cpp
class A {
public:
    int ID;

    A() {}

    A(int getID) {
        ID = getID;
    }
};

class B {
public:
    A someA;
    A someB;
    int number;

    B() {}

    B(A ObjectA, A ObjectB, int getNumber) {
        someA = ObjectA;
        someB = ObjectB;
        number = getNumber;
    }
};
```

Comment: Adding a default constructor may not be relevant in general.